# Why is my f2py programs slower than python programs

Tags: python, performance, fortran, f2py

I recently wrote a time consuming program with python and decided to rewrite the most time consuming part with fortran.

However, the fortran code, wrapped with f2py, is slower than python code, Can anyone tell me how to find what is happening here?

For reference, here's the python function:

```
def iterative_method(alpha0, beta0, epsilon0, epsilons0, omega, smearing=0.01, precision=0.01, max_step=20, flag=0):
    # alpha0, beta0, epsilon0, epsilons0 are numpy arrays
    m, n = np.shape(epsilon0)
    Omega = np.eye(m, dtype=np.complex) * (omega + smearing * 1j)
    green = LA.inv(Omega - epsilon0) # LA is numpy.linalg
    alpha = np.dot(alpha0, np.dot(green, alpha0))
    beta = np.dot(beta0, np.dot(green, beta0))
    epsilon = epsilon0 + np.dot(alpha0, np.dot(green, beta0)) + np.dot(beta0, np.dot(green, alpha0))
    epsilons = epsilons0 + np.dot(alpha0, np.dot(green, beta0))

    while np.max(np.abs(alpha0)) > precision and np.max(np.abs(beta0)) > precision and flag < max_step:
        flag += 1
        return iterative_method(alpha, beta, epsilon, epsilons, omega, smearing, precision, min_step, max_step, flag)
return epsilon, epsilons, flag
```

The corresponding fortran code is

```
SUBROUTINE iterate(eout, esout, alpha, beta, e, es, omega, smearing, prec, max_step, rank)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    REAL(kind=dp) :: omega, smearing, prec
    INTEGER :: max_step, step, rank, cnt
    COMPLEX(kind=dp) :: alpha(rank,rank), beta(rank,rank), omega_mat(rank, rank),&
     green(rank, rank), e(rank,rank), es(rank,rank)
    COMPLEX(kind=dp), INTENT(out) :: eout(rank, rank), esout(rank, rank)
    step = 0
    omega_mat = 0
    DO cnt=1, rank
        omega_mat(cnt, cnt) = 1.0_dp
    ENDDO
    omega_mat = omega_mat * (omega + (0.0_dp, 1.0_dp) * smearing)
    DO WHILE (maxval(abs(alpha)) .gt. prec .or.  maxval(abs(beta)) .gt. prec .and. step .lt. max_step)
        green = zInverse(rank, omega_mat - e) ! zInverse is calling lapack to compute inverse of the matrix
        e = e + matmul(alpha, matmul(green, beta)) + matmul(beta, matmul(green, alpha))
        es = es + matmul(alpha, matmul(green, beta))
        alpha = matmul(alpha, matmul(green, alpha))
        beta = matmul(beta, matmul(green, beta))
        step = step + 1
    ENDDO
    print *, step
    eout = e
    esout = es
END SUBROUTINE iterate
```

In a test, python code used about 5 seconds while fortran code used about 7 seconds, which is hardly acceptable. Also, I can hardly see any overhead in fortran code. Is the wrapper to be blamed?

**Edit:** I didn't use `BlAS` for `matmul`. After using `BLAS`, fortran and python performace are both around 5 seconds.

Comment: Is your matmul using BLAS at all?

Comment: The `return` statement in your Python code seems misplaced because its within a `while` loop. That could certainly make it appear faster...

Comment: @martineau, why so? It's a iteration and does the same thing as their fortran counterpart.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact it was returning a recursive call to itself...although I still find it an odd implementation, since [Python does not do tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#By_language) (afaik).

Comment: @VladimirF, question edited.

Comment: Why is it not acceptable? Try to find a faster BLAS library then.

Comment: @VladimirF, Because one of my colleagues wrote a program with C which is at least 20 times faster than mine. I think fortran should at least have the same performance as C. He was using MKL. Do BLAS and MKL differ so much in performance?

Comment: Unless you show us the C program we can't say anything at all. You may be just using a slow algorithm.

Comment: The title says and the first paragraphs say something else. Edit the whole question, do not add some **Edit** part. But do not invalidate existing answers with too radical edits.

Comment: @VladimirF, It seems necessary to ask another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968682/how-to-obtain-how-much-time-is-spent-in-f2py-wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) on the python code so you know exactly how it spends its time.
Then, you can do a similar thing on the Fortran code using a debugger, if you like.

I suspect essentially *all* of the time goes into matrix operations, so any speed difference is due to the math library, not to the language that calls it.
[*This post*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) relays some of my experience doing that.
Often the routines to do things like matrix multiplication, inverse, or Cholesky transform, are designed to be efficient on large matrices, but not on small.

For example, the LAPACK matrix-multiplication routine DGEMM has two character arguments, TRANSA and TRANSB, which can be upper or lower case, specifying whether each input matrix is transposed.
To examine the value of those arguments, it calls a function LSAME.
I found that, if I am spending a large fraction of my time multiplying small matrices, like 4x4, the program actually spends nearly all of its time calling LSAME, and very little time actually multiplying matrices.
You can see how it would be easy to fix that.

Comment: I find it difficult to calculate how much time is spent in `f2py` wrappers. Is there a convenient way?

Comment: @ChongWang: Can you run it under GDB and [*pause it manually*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). If you do this 20 times, the fraction of samples containing matrix operations equals the fraction of time they take. It's not a high-precision measurement, but you don't need high precision.