# How to obtain how much time is spent in f2py wrappers

Tags: python, fortran, profiling, f2py

I am currently writing a time consuming python program and decided to rewrite part of the program in fortran. However, the performance is still not good. For profiling purpose, I want to know how much time is spent in `f2py` wrappers and how much time is actual spent in fortran subroutines. Is there a convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: take a look on cProfile, otherwise you could always split some timings into your code here and there?

Comment: It seems cProfile doesn't dig into f2py wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found out `-DF2PY_REPORT_ATEXIT` option can report wrapper performance.